# CSS background-color transition not working in specific browsers (desktop + mobile)

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, css-transitions, transition

I have this SCSS that, in theory, should transition the background color smoothly, but it is not smooth in specific browsers.

See this codepen for a demo: http://codepen.io/ahegyi/pen/Wvjajy

(Click on the photo or note text to activate the transition. It's more obvious if you click on the text.)

```
.overlay {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;

  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

  &.reveal {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  &.conceal {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  }
}
```

In Chrome desktop (version 42.0.2311.152, Mac OS 10.9) and Firefox desktop (version 36.0.4, Mac OS 10.9), the transitions are smooth.

However, in Safari (both desktop v7.1.3 + mobile Safari on iOS 8.1.3) and Chrome mobile on iOS (v 38.0.2125.59) do not transition, and instead snap directly.

Can anyone reproduce this issue? Is this a bug in certain versions of WebKit, or am I missing something here? Could it be that other transitions I use interact poorly with this particular transition? (In parallel, I'm also using a height transition on `.mark-note-text h2`, and a jQuery slide effect on the `.mark-content` div.)

Comment: Not sure I follow - what's the ampersand for?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the perceived snapping effect on my phone (iOS Safari 8.0). Can I Use says `transition` should be supported: (http://caniuse.com/#search=transition). I'm wondering if this transition is ignored in iOS due to optimized battery performance settings?

Comment: @Katana314 That's SCSS syntax. [Read up](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

Comment: @gmeben Sorry, failed to notice it in the question description. I at first thought to look in the tags, but it wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by a syntax error in your externally loaded CSS.

In [this file](https://d2deec0tjmv48q.cloudfront.net/assets/application-75b7809171928eae4419e2c662e7688f.css), you will find this code.

```
.mark-object .overlay{-webkit-transition:background-color, 200ms, ease;-moz-transition:background-color, 200ms, ease;-ms-transition:background-color, 200ms, ease;-o-transition:background-color, 200ms, ease;transition:background-color, 200ms, ease;
```

Which looks like this beautified.

```
.mark-object .overlay {
    -webkit-transition: background-color, 200ms, ease;
       -moz-transition: background-color, 200ms, ease;
        -ms-transition: background-color, 200ms, ease;
         -o-transition: background-color, 200ms, ease;
            transition: background-color, 200ms, ease;
```

As you can see, there are commas between the properties, the duration, and the easing function, but there should only be commas to delimit different properties.

Also, the CSS you have in your CodePen is less-specific than your external CSS, so it has no effect. [If you were to increase the specificity, your pen would work.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wadYQx)

You can see how Safari is error-handling this in the applied styles.

[image: Safari inspector]

However, Firefox error handles it in a different way, assuming `all` for the bare settings.

[image: Firefox inspector]

We can see from the computed styles that non-iOS Chrome does the same as Firefox.

[image: Chrome styles]

Of course, the reason Chrome behaves the same as Safari on iOS is because iOS Chrome uses the same rendering engine as Safari, as per Apple's requirement.

Comment: Wow - super descriptive answer, thanks so much for the long explanation. I assumed since Safari's computed `transition` wasn't error'ed or strikethrough'ed, it was parsing correctly. If only all of life's troubles were just commas in the wrong places. Thanks also for catching the specificity of my added SCSS, and for the note about iOS Chrome using Safari's rendering engine -- good to know.